# Multi access token type in IdentityServer4

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have an Api that every user can have multi pages.
I want to give access to clients separately.
Something like Facebook multi access token types.
How can i implement this in IdentityServer?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to restrict api access for clients, the way you should go is to use scopes(api scopes).

Take a look at docs how to restrict scopes: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/apis.html#validating-scopes.